# Undefined array index error in PHP

Tags: php

Hello everybody I have some strange problem with this very simple code:

```
    if($_GET['task'] == 'dropMenu') dropMenus($_GET['id'], $_GET['val']);

    function dropMenus($elemId, $elemValue){
    global $pdo;


    switch($elemId){
      case 'bank':
      $dbTable = 'bank';
      $cellName = 'bankname';
      break;

    case 'tipe':
      $dbTable = 'cardtype';
      $cellName = 'type';
      break;

    case 'holder':
      $dbTable = 'cardholder';
      $cellName = 'holdername';
      break;

    }//end switch()


    $result = $pdo->query('select * from bank '.$dbTable);

    foreach($result as $row){
       $dbArray[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row[$cellName]);
    }//end foreach
    }//end dropMenus
```

If `$elemId = 'bank'` everything works fine, but if `$elemId = 'tipe'`  for some reason I receive this message:

> Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\financeStat\cards\cardsImprove\cards.php on line (the line where is  $dbArray[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row[$cellName]))

or `$elemId = 'holder'` the message is:

> Notice: Undefined index: holdername in C:\xampp\htdocs\financeStat\cards\cardsImprove\cards.php on line (the line where is  $dbArray[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row[$cellName]))

Any idea?

Comment: `var_dump($row, $cellName);`

Comment: Sidenote: The number of opening/closing braces do not match (in your posted code) You have 3x `{` for 2x `}`. Try adding another `}` after `}//end switch()`

Comment: My guess.. there is no "type" or "holdername" fields in db result.

Comment: Fredd -ii, in my code they match, I just took partialy the code that doesn't work properly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hardy, nothing is wrong with DB. There are those fields in the coresponding tables.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense to me - 'select * from bank cardholder'. is your table name 'bank cardholder' or 'bank_cardholder'?

Comment: I just noticed that now @Yani - Most confusing. Good catch btw. But I'm not going to put in an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `type` or `holdername` fields in db results. That what your error is saying. Check your database results.

Comment: And what about `$elemId = 'holder'` ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: type

Comment: Yes, but did you read what the OP wrote in the question? *"but if $elemId = 'tipe' **or** $elemId = 'holder' for some reason I receive this message:"* - All the more reasons I **never** put in answers for questions like these.

Comment: Hardy you were completely right!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the fact that `$row` does not contain the fields `type` or `cardholder`. I would check the output of your db request by doing:

```
 $result = $pdo->query('select * from'.$dbTable);
```

This will show you what exactly is in the `$row` variable.

Comment: The problem line is $result = $pdo->query('select * from bank '.$dbTable). It should be: $result = $pdo->query('select * from '.$dbTable). Stupid mistake.